# Docker: Add a restart policy to a container that was already created

Tags: docker

I see that Docker has added something called restarting policies to handle restart of containers in case of, for instance, reboot.

While this is very useful, I see that the restart policy command just work with `docker run` and not `docker start`. So my question is:

Is there any way to add restarting policies to a container that was already created in the past?

Comment: You should change the accepted answer to @Yale Huang's one. The accepted answer is incorrect with current versions of docker. I understand the answer might have helped you back then but now it's misleading.

Answer (score 746, accepted):

In recent versions of docker (as of 1.11) you have an [`update`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/update/#/update-a-container-s-restart-policy) command:

```
docker update --restart=always <container>
```

Comment: Should be the accepted answer with the caveat that it works as of Docker 1.11.

Comment: with docker 17.09 I had to run `docker update --restart always <container>` https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/start-containers-automatically/

Comment: `sudo docker ps | cut -f1 -d' ' | tail -n +2 | xargs sudo docker update --restart=always` -- this will update all running containers. You might want to compare the output to docker ps to make sure the tail part is still skipping the appropriate amount of lines and not excluding the first container.

Comment: `docker ps -q` gives you just the IDs (each per line), so just use ithat in front of `| xargs docker update --restart=always`

Comment: `docker update` accepts multiple container IDs, so no need for `xargs` at all, just do `docker update --restart=always $(docker ps -q)`.

Comment: Use: `docker update --restart=no <container_id>` to prevent from restarting again.

Comment: This is helpful. I have been recreating my containers this whole time (`docker-compose down; docker-compose up -d`)!!!!

Comment: It should be noted that if you're using docker-compose, you must still put `restart: always` in your docker-compose.yml file in order for the restart policy to persist. `docker update` only applies to a particular running container, and `docker-compose up` works by deleting the old container (including the restart policy you set with `docker update`) and creating a fresh one with the restart policy in `docker-compose.yml`.

Answer (score 50):

There're two approaches to modify RestartPolicy:

- Find out the container ID, stop the whole docker service, modify /var/lib/docker/containers/CONTAINER_ID/hostconfig.json, set RestartPolicy -> Name to "always", and start docker service.
- `docker commit` your container as a new image, stop & rm the current container,  and start a new container with the image.

Comment: stop container, edit, start container. works like a charm. I don't know why editing is disabled.

Comment: Worked for me on an old server with docker 1.10 (don’t ask ). Sadly `docker update` allows to modify restart policy only on 1.11+

Answer (score 1):

Using `--restart=always` policy will handle restart of existing containers in case of reboot.

The problem is that if there are ***multiple containers*** with `--restart=always` when you run image of a newer version as discussed in *[docker - how do you disable auto-restart on a container?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37599128/4058484)*.

> Trying to automatically remove the container when it exist by put
>   option `docker run --rm` will also problem with the `--restart=always`
>   policy since **they are conflicting each others**.

```
$ docker run --rm --restart always <image>
Conflicting options: --restart and --rm
```

So in this case it is better to choose another option: **--restart unless-stopped** policy.

```
$ docker run --rm --restart unless-stopped <image>
```

This policy ***will not conflicting*** the `docker run --rm` but as explained in *[docker documentation](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/start-containers-automatically/)*:

> It similar to `--restart=always`, except that when the **container is stopped
>   (manually or otherwise)**, it is not restarted even after Docker daemon
>   restarts.

So when using this `--restart unless-stopped` policy, to ensure the restarting is working in case it stop by accident when you close the terminal, do once **in another terminal** as below:

```
$ docker ps
$ docker restart <container>
```

Wait until the killing process end in the previous shell, then close it and just leave (**don't do exit**).
And check again in the remained terminal if the container is still running:

```
$ docker ps
```

If it is still running the you can safely reboot and check again that the application is restarting and see your docker is clean without unused of multiple containers.