# How to restart an existing Docker container in restart="always" mode?

Tags: docker

When you initially run a Docker container from an image you can specify the option:

```
--restart="always"
```

This ensures that the container is always restarted by the Docker daemon if for some reason it stops. So you could run a container like so:

```
docker run --restart="always" <IMAGE>
```

Also you can restart an existing Docker container by specifying its container ID, i.e.:

```
docker start <CONTAINER ID>
```

However I can't determine if it's possible to change an existing container, that originally was not run with the `--restart="always"` option, to convert it to always restart in future.

Currently the only way I can think to do this is to save the container as a new image and then run that image as a new container with the `--restart="always"` option. Would this in fact be the correct way to do this?

**EDIT**: What I perhaps didn't make clear enough originally is that I am thinking about the situation where there have been changes in the container since it was originally run, which need to be persisted. So just running a new container from the original image would not be sufficient.

Comment: More or less duplicates: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26852321/docker-add-a-restart-policy-to-a-container-that-was-already-created

Answer (score 113, accepted):

We now have docker [update](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/update/), which allows changing the restart policy of a running container.

```
docker update --restart=always <CONTAINER ID>
```

There are three other options:

- no (default)
- on-failure
- unless-stopped

Please refer to the [link](https://blog.codeship.com/ensuring-containers-are-always-running-with-dockers-restart-policy/) for details.

Comment: In what version of Docker was this introduced?

Comment: It is available since version 1.11.0.

Comment: How come we cant see this in kitematic anybody know?

Answer (score 15):

Ok, so to answer my own question, it seems that it's not possible just to restart the same container with `--restart=always`, because that's something you have to do when you *run* a container for the first time and not a parameter that you can use when you *start* an existing container.

There are three possible work-arounds to this:

1. As @user2915097 stated, you can abandon the original container (stopping it and then deleting it with `docker rm <CONTAINER ID>`to tidy up). Then just run a new container from the original image specifying the `-restart=always` option this time.
2. If no volumes were used, so the changes are internal to the container, you need to commit the container to a new image and then run a new container from that image.

   `docker commit <CONTAINER ID> <NEW IMAGE NAME>`

   `docker run -d --restart=always ... <NEW IMAGE NAME>`
3. If volumes were used and all changes are restricted to the volumes, then you can run a second container with the `--volumes-from` parameter without having to commit a new version of the image. i.e.

   - `docker stop <CONTAINER 1 NAME>`
   - `docker run -d --restart=always --volumes-from <CONTAINER 1 NAME> ... <ORIGINAL IMAGE NAME>`

   It would then be safe to delete Container 1, as the volumes will not be deleted whilst another container continues to use them.

I guess there is a fourth possibility too; if you used a volume(s) *and* you know that there have been changes to the container that aren't on the volume, then you'll have to use a combination of (2) and (3).

Answer (score 3):

**Update: This worked to enable restart.  But setting it back to no and it gets reset back to always and the container starts again! :( I'm going to leave this answer here in case someone figures out how this really works.  I must be close!**

Folks, I've found the most hacky solution that gets around copying containers etc.

> vi /var/lib/docker/containers/$(docker inspect -f '{{ .Id }}' $ContainerID)/hostconfig.json

Search for "RestartPolicy".  Set it to "no", "always" etc

Maybe someone could wrap that up in a script!?

Anyway, that piece of json along with the config.json would allow you to modify all sorts of things that you missed when creating your container.

Comment: A word of warning to anyone who tries this, A lot of Docker's state management operates with the assumption that it's the only thing modifying the contents of /var/lib/docker. Be very careful when making changes here.

Comment: Ah yeah, depends what changes are made and what files are kept open.  To be on the safe side feel free to stop your docker engine.  I hope they add the ability to make changes in subsequent releases.  It's crazy not having the ability manipulate the restart policy.

Comment: A new set feature may be added soon.  https://github.com/docker/docker/pull/15078

Answer (score 0):

extract from http://www.brandpending.com/blog/2014/11/21/setting-and-re-setting-the-restart-behaviour-of-a-docker-container

> So let say you want to change the restart policy of this container
>   from always to on-failure. To do this, you need to stop the container,
>   remove it and re-run it with the new restart policy.

Comment: But the problem with this is you would lose any changes in the original container because you've deleted it and created a new one from scratch.

I'm pretty sure that committing a new image and running a new container from that would be better, if there have been any changes in the original container that need to be persisted.

Comment: So we are back to your commit

Comment: @rdc you should try to avoid having changes in containers because of things like this - either keep it in a volume or a DB of some sort.

Comment: This answer in no longer relevant, check out @Frank Wong's answer