# Restart docker automatically

Tags: docker, containers

I have a web application in a docker container, and it processes requests via HTTP. But, when there are too many requests app stops working. I am busy with other tasks, so don't really have time to fix it. When it crashes, the container is still running, but the app responds with a 500 error. Are there any ways to track it and restart docker automatically, because I don't have an option to check it all the time?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How restart a stopped docker container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39666950/how-restart-a-stopped-docker-container)

Comment: Or this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41555884/docker-what-does-docker-run-restart-always-actually-do

Comment: Or this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30040971/how-to-automatically-monitor-and-restart-the-docker-container-when-it-crashes-do

Comment: Thanks for these threads. But in my situation container is successfully running, but the app inside it crashes

Comment: Then why not restart your application within that container? If the container itself is not the problem, this does not look related to Docker itself to me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest you:

1. Create the container with the restart policy set to `always` or `unless-stopped` or `on-failure`.
2. Instrument [Docker Health Check](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#healthcheck) like `HEALTHCHECK --interval=5m --timeout=3s CMD curl -f http://localhost/ || exit 1`.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know that the HEALTHCHECK existed. I guess, I need to read the documentation more thoroughly