# When trying to setup data persistence after server reboot have got status exited (255) for all containers

Tags: docker, hyperledger-fabric

I am trying to setup data persistence in startFabric example,
hyperledger fabric 1.4.2

I set `live-restore: true` in `daemon.json` and

```
 volumes:
      - /var/hyperledger/couchdb0:/opt/couchdb/data
```

in `docker-compose-couch.yaml`

After I restart docker service it works, but when I reboot server all containers have status exited with code 255. However if I restart containers manually using command docker restart container_id, it works again.

Comment: what do you expect when restarting the server ? that is the normal since the containers are killed

Comment: Try adding restart policy on your stack like so: --restart always

Comment: @LinPy According docker docs [https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/live-restore/] Starting with Docker Engine 1.12, you can configure the daemon so that containers remain running if the daemon becomes unavailable.

Answer (score 1):

From the Docs:

> Live restore upon restart
>
> The live restore option only works to restore containers if the daemon
>   options, such as bridge IP addresses and graph driver, did not change.
>   If any of these daemon-level configuration options have changed, the
>   live restore may not work and you may need to manually stop the
>   containers.

beside the live restore meant to keep Containers up when the daemon is down not when restarting the Server (the containers will be down)

so you need to take a look at [this](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/start-containers-automatically/) it seems that what you need.

Comment: Thank you @LinPy. [This is detailed description of restart policy](https://blog.codeship.com/ensuring-containers-are-always-running-with-dockers-restart-policy/) and [how to change restart policy for existing container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29603504/how-to-restart-an-existing-docker-container-in-restart-always-mode)