# How to stop a docker container which started with `--restart=always`

Tags: docker

Is there any way to stop a docker container which started with **`--restart=always`** like following

`sudo docker run -it --restart=always <image_id>`

Comment: This is duplicate of

 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26852321/docker-add-a-restart-policy-to-a-container-that-was-already-created

Comment: Hi, I asked a similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76127700/docker-container-keeps-running-after-system-was-pruned

I wasn't able to find a solution to my problem as `docker ps` returns nothing

Answer (score 127, accepted):

Here's the mighty eagle that docker has recently included. :D

You can [`update`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/update/) docker container.

use **`sudo docker update --restart=no <container_id>`** to update `--restart` flag of the container.

Now you can [`stop`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/stop/) the container.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to just use docker stop and then docker rm to make sure the container doesn't restart when the daemon restarts.

Your question is an issue on the docker [github](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/11008) and someone has made some comments about to how to solve [here](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/10032)

> I'm not sure if it's intended behavior to restart a stopped container on daemon restart... but for sure docker rm  would be all that is needed, no need to remove the image.

Comment: When you mention `--restart=always`, container will automatically start if you `stop` it.

Comment: @RafafTahsin, no it won't. Only if you restart the Docker daemon.

Comment: If there is something wrong with the container, so it gets stuck in restarting, You either have to use the update trick or stop the deamon so it wont restart.

Answer (score 1):

If you use docker stop or docker kill, you're manually stopping the container so it will not restart. You can do some tests about restart policies: restarting the docker daemon, rebooting your server, using a CMD inside a container and running an exit...

See this answer for more details:

https://serverfault.com/a/884823/381420

Comment: That's not the case, I've seen docker kept restarting even on manual stop

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR**

Also check docker swarm if there are any stacks that spin up containers there. Simply run `docker stack ls` followed by `docker rm <stack_name>`.

---

**Longer version**

This is not exactly an answer to your question, but I had a very similar issue where containers kept spinning up even if I ran `docker update --restart=no <container_id>`, `docker stop <container_id>` and `docker rm <container_id>`. These were some old containers, so I had no clue how I generated them.

After some Googling, I realized that it was a docker swarm stack that kept spinning up containers. By running `docker stack ls` followed by `docker rm <stack_name>`, I was able to stop the auto spin-up of the containers and thus remove them entirely.