# Docker container keeps running after system was pruned

Tags: python, docker, plotly-dash, gunicorn

Yesterday I discovered that a container was still running on my machine (macOS Monterey). I searched StackOverflow for answers to my issue but anything I tried didn't work.

I did a `docker ps` and then a `docker stop <container-ID>` but the web app was still running in port `0.0.0.0:80`.

I don't remember when I run this container but it was during the development of a Dash Plotly app.

After the above failed I tried:

```
docker system prune --all --force --volumes
```

which removed all containers and images from my system (it did work because the image indeed disappeared from my Docker Desktop list).

I then restarted my computer but the web app was still there.

I then run the command:

```
sudo lsof -i -P -n | grep 80
```

which gave me the output:

```
assistant  480       cconsta1   25u  IPv4 0x7f28d5520c917253      0t0    UDP *:*
Google     730       cconsta1   80u  IPv6 0x7f28d5520a8477c3      0t0    UDP *:5353
Google     730       cconsta1   89u  IPv6 0x7f28d5520a8480f3      0t0    UDP *:5353
Slack\x20 4259       cconsta1   23u  IPv4 0x7f28d54d343d66cb      0t0    TCP 192.168.10.1:51807->3.65.102.105:443 (ESTABLISHED)
Slack\x20 4259       cconsta1   26u  IPv4 0x7f28d54d339966cb      0t0    TCP 192.168.10.1:51809->3.65.102.105:443 (ESTABLISHED)
httpd     4418           root    4u  IPv6 0x7f28d53edaecb713      0t0    TCP *:80 (LISTEN)
httpd     4422           _www    4u  IPv6 0x7f28d53edaecb713      0t0    TCP *:80 (LISTEN)
httpd     4431           _www    4u  IPv6 0x7f28d53edaecb713      0t0    TCP *:80 (LISTEN)
httpd     4433           _www    4u  IPv6 0x7f28d53edaecb713      0t0    TCP *:80 (LISTEN)
httpd     4434           _www    4u  IPv6 0x7f28d53edaecb713      0t0    TCP *:80 (LISTEN)
```

I tried to kill these processes to see if something will work out, `sudo kill -9 <PID>` but that didn't work either.

Finally, I cleared my browser's cache and checked whether the web app runs in private mode but it still works.

I don't remember which `Dockerfile` I used to run this container but this one is the closest:

```
FROM python:3.10

# EXPOSE 8050

WORKDIR /app

COPY . .
COPY models /app/models/

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

EXPOSE 8050

CMD ["gunicorn", "-b", "0.0.0.0:8050", "--reload", "app:server"]
```

The image was probably built using:

```
docker build -f Dockerfile -t app:latest .
```

and run using:

```
docker run -p 80:8050 app:latest
```

This is the `requirements.txt` file:

```
numpy 
pandas 
plotly 
dash 
gunicorn  
dash-bootstrap-components
scikit-learn 
xgboost
```

The `app.py` file looks like this:

```py
import time
import dash
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc
import pickle
import numpy as np
import plotly.graph_objs as go
from dash import Input, Output, State, dcc, html
# import tensorflow as tf
# from tensorflow import keras
# from keras.models import load_model
#import xgboost
import re


app = dash.Dash(external_stylesheets=[
                dbc.themes.COSMO])


# Include the server option to become able to deploy online
server = app.server

# Code for the app


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run_server(debug=True, host="0.0.0.0",port="8050", use_reloader=True)
    #app.run_server(debug=True)
```

The command `docker --version` returns:

```
Docker version 20.10.24, build 297e128
```

Edit: I think that the image was actually run using the `restart always` command:

```
docker run --restart always -p 80:8050 app:latest
```

Comment: I also tried uninstalling Docker completely but the process is still there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of searching around, I first figured out that the service causing the problem was the Apache Server, `httpd`. I listed all services running on port `80` using this:

```
sudo lsof -i :80
```

Trying to kill the process using

```
sudo kill -9 <process_id>
```

didn't do anything, while using

```
sudo pkill httpd
```

was stopping the web service for a few seconds, but it was then coming back. I was able to stop the server using:

```
sudo apachectl stop
```

To prevent it from restarting, I edited the file `/etc/apache2/httpd.conf`, and specifically I commented out this line:

```
#LoadModule mpm_prefork_module
```

Before doing all these I uninstalled and reinstalled Docker but that didn't do anything.