# How to check if the docker engine and a docker container are running?

Tags: bash, docker

In a script, I need to check:

a) Is the docker engine running?
b) Given a container name, is that docker container running?

Comment: Any docker command (except docker -v), like docker ps

Comment: `docker attach containerName`

Comment: or try  `docker ps`

Comment: sudo systemctl status docker

Comment: `docker ps` ----- This command will only show RUNNING containers

Comment: docker ps -a will show all the container with the status as well. Hope it helps

Comment: If using wsl2 on Windows, see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57108228

Answer (score 216):

If you are looking for a specific container, you can run:

```
if [ "$( docker container inspect -f '{{.State.Running}}' $container_name )" = "true" ]; then ...
```

To avoid issues with a container that is in a crash loop and constantly restarting from showing that it's up, the above can be improved by checking the `Status` field:

```
if [ "$( docker container inspect -f '{{.State.Status}}' $container_name )" = "running" ]; then ...
```

If you want to know if dockerd is running itself on the local machine and you have systemd installed, you can run:

```
systemctl show --property ActiveState docker
```

You can also connect to docker with `docker info` or `docker version` and they will error out if the daemon is unavailable.

Comment: how would you put the `docker inspect …` inside a `if` statement of a bash script?

Comment: `if [ $(docker inspect -f '{{.State.Running}}' $container_name) = "true" ]; then echo yup; else echo nope; fi`

Comment: Correction: "docker version" produces regular output even if docker is not running. "docker info" shows an error indicating that docker is not running.

Comment: @VeganHunter `docker version` produces output, but it also generates an error. The return code will be 1, not 0, and there will be a line for the server side check stating "Cannot connect to the Docker daemon...".

Comment: I use `docker inspect -f '{{.State.Restarting}}' $container_name` since I start my container with a restart policy, though here "true" is what you want to avoid.

Comment: Both bash and docker will complain for the above `if` statement, when the container is not running.  This hides the unwanted spew for the false case:  `if [ "$(docker inspect -f '{{.State.Running}}' ${container_name} 2>/dev/null)" = "true" ]; then echo yup; else echo nope; fi`

Comment: `systemctl : The term 'systemctl' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program`

Comment: @MarcoLackovic sounds like you missed the "you have systemd installed" part above.

Comment: @BMitch 's command seems to not work on the newest version of docker (running containers names have some additional characters ) . I posted as an answer the script that works well for me on all stations at work :)

Answer (score 143):

I ended up using

```
docker info
```

to check with a bash script if docker engine is running.

EDIT: which can be used to fail your script if docker isn't running, like so:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
if ! docker info > /dev/null 2>&1; then
  echo "This script uses docker, and it isn't running - please start docker and try again!"
  exit 1
fi
```

Comment: This answer is underrated. It's cross-platform and passes/fails quickly.

Comment: `docker info > /dev/null 2>&1` if you don't need the output

Answer (score 37):

List all containers:

`docker container ls -a`

`ls` = list
`-a` = all

Check the column "status"

Comment: That's what i needed, because it work on every platforms !!

Comment: easy and simple ... WORKED.

Answer (score 32):

you can check docker state using: `systemctl is-active docker`

```
➜  ~  systemctl is-active docker
active
```

you can use it as:

```
➜  ~  if [ "$(systemctl is-active docker)" = "active" ]; then echo "is alive :)" ; fi
is alive :)

➜  ~  sudo systemctl stop docker

➜  ~  if [ "$(systemctl is-active docker)" = "active" ]; then echo "is alive :)" ; fi
 * empty response *
```

Comment: This don't answer the question. _"to check with container name"_

Comment: yeah it seems the question is ambiguous, to check if container is running you should use `docker ps --filter name=pattern`, then you can format the output to check only the status adding this flag: `--format {{.Status}}`

Comment: This will tell you if `systemctl` *thinks* `docker` is running, but it will not actually check if docker REALLY is running. So the `docker info` command above is a better choice, IMHO

Answer (score 26):

For OS X users (Mojave 10.14.3)

Here is what i use in my Bash script to test if Docker is running or not

```
# Check if docker is running
if ! docker info >/dev/null 2>&1; then
    echo "Docker does not seem to be running, run it first and retry"
    exit 1
fi
```

Comment: I refactored this to remove the [`if [[ $? -ne 0 ]]` antipattern.](/questions/36313216/why-is-testing-to-see-if-a-command-succeeded-or-not-an-anti-pattern)

Answer (score 15):

Any docker command (except `docker -v`), like `docker ps`
If Docker is running, you'll get some valid response, otherwise you'll get a message that includes "Is your docker daemon up and running?"

You can also check your task manager.

Comment: interestingly `docker -v` doesn't check if docker is running, but `docker version` does ! LOL

Answer (score 15):

Sometimes you don't know the full container name, in this case this is what worked for me:

```
if docker ps | grep -q keyword
then 
    echo "Running!"
else
    echo "Not running!"
    exit 1
fi
```

We list all the running container processes (`docker ps -a` would show us also not running ones, but that's not what I needed), we search for a specific word (`grep` part) and simply fail if we did not find at least one running container whose name contains our keyword.

Comment: Refactored to remove a massive collection of [shell programming antipatterns.](http://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html#wc)

Answer (score 15):

container status: true/false

```
# docker inspect --format '{{json .State.Running}}' container-name
true
#
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Comment: For anyone else following this, if you are looking for a health check on a container, this is good. It will return true if it's working

Comment: This does not seem to work anymore.  "State" is not one of the keys in the JSOn that gets returned. Not seeing anything about running or health either. But it is up, and I am getting a JSON response.

Comment: Works flawlessly

Comment: Need a bit of explanation in the answer but this works!

Answer (score 9):

You can check with this command `systemctl status docker` it will show the status of the docker. If you want to start you can use `systemctl start docker` instead of `systemctl` you can try also with `service`, `service docker status` and `service docker start` respectively.

Comment: This answer assumes the end-user is using `systemd` as their init.

Comment: `systemctl status docker` correctly show is docker service is running. Thank you.

Answer (score 9):

You can also check if a particular docker container is running or not using following command:

```
docker inspect postgres | grep "Running"
```

This command will check if for example my postgres container is running or not and will return output as **"Running": true**

Hope this helps.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. And it works.  (It's good when people who vote something down say why, so noobs can learn better SO etiquette. :) )

Comment: I didn't vote down, but "Error: No such object: postgres"

Comment: @ged `postgres` is the name of the container, not a command.

Answer (score 9):

`docker ps -a`

You can see all docker containers whether it is alive or dead.

Answer (score 8):

For the answer to your first question refer to this answer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/65447848/4691279

For your second question - you can use command like `docker ps --filter "name=<<<YOUR_CONTAINER_NAME>>>"` to check whether a particular container is running or not.

- If Docker and Container both are running then you will get output like below:

  ```
  $ docker ps --filter "name=nostalgic_stallman"

  CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES       
  9b6247364a03        busybox             "top"               2 minutes ago       Up 2 minutes                            nostalgic_stallman
  ```
- If Docker is not running then you will get an error message saying docker daemon is not running.
- If Docker running but Container is not running then you will not get the container name in the output of this command.

Answer (score 6):

Run this command in the terminal:

```
docker ps
```

If docker is not running, you wil get this message:

> Error response from daemon: dial unix docker.raw.sock: connect: connection refused

Answer (score 5):

Run:

```
docker version
```

If docker **is running** you will see:

```
Client: Docker Engine - Community
 Version:           ...
 [omitted]

Server: Docker Engine - Community
 Engine:
  Version:          ...
 [omitted]
```

If docker **is not running** you will see:

```
Client: Docker Engine - Community
 Version:           ...
 [omitted]

Error response from daemon: Bad response from Docker engine
```

Comment: For Windows users, if the engine is not running, you may also see an error like: **error during connect: Get http://%2F%2F.%2Fpipe%2Fdocker_engine/v1.35/info: open //./pipe/docker_engine**

Answer (score 3):

I have a more fleshed out example of using some of the work above in the context of a Gitea container, but it could easily be converted to another container based on the name. Also, you could probably use the `docker ps --filter` capability to set $GITEA_CONTAINER in a newer system or one without docker-compose in use.

```
# Set to name or ID of the container to be watched.
GITEA_CONTAINER=$(./bin/docker-compose ps |grep git|cut -f1 -d' ')

# Set timeout to the number of seconds you are willing to wait.
timeout=500; counter=0
# This first echo is important for keeping the output clean and not overwriting the previous line of output.
echo "Waiting for $GITEA_CONTAINER to be ready (${counter}/${timeout})"
#This says that until docker inspect reports the container is in a running state, keep looping.
until [[ $(docker inspect --format '{{json .State.Running}}' $GITEA_CONTAINER) == true ]]; do

  # If we've reached the timeout period, report that and exit to prevent running an infinite loop.
  if [[ $timeout -lt $counter ]]; then
    echo "ERROR: Timed out waiting for $GITEA_CONTAINER to come up."
    exit 1
  fi

  # Every 5 seconds update the status
  if (( $counter % 5 == 0 )); then
    echo -e "\e[1A\e[KWaiting for $GITEA_CONTAINER to be ready (${counter}/${timeout})"
  fi

  # Wait a second and increment the counter
  sleep 1s
  ((counter++))

done
```

Answer (score 2):

on a Mac you might see the image:

[image]

if you right click on the docker icon then you see:

[image]

alternatively:

`docker ps`

and

`docker run hello-world`

Answer (score 2):

If the underlying goal is "How can I start a container when Docker starts?"

We can use Docker's [restart policy](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/start-containers-automatically/)

To add a restart policy to an existing container:

[Docker: Add a restart policy to a container that was already created](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26852321/docker-add-a-restart-policy-to-a-container-that-was-already-created)

Example:

```
docker update --restart=always <container>
```

Answer (score 1):

How I check in SSH.Run:

```
systemctl
```

If response: Failed to get D-Bus connection: Operation not permitted

Its a docker or WSL container.

Answer (score 1):

Checking for .State.Status, .State.Running, etc. will tell you if it's running, but it's better to ensure that the [health](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#healthcheck) of your containers. Below is a script that you can run that will make sure that two containers are in good health before executing a command in the 2nd container. It prints out the docker logs if the wait time/attempts threshold has been reached.

Example taken from [npm sql-mdb](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#healthcheck).

```
#!/bin/bash
# Wait for two docker healthchecks to be in a "healthy" state before executing a "docker exec -it $2 bash $3"
##############################################################################################################################
# $1 Docker container name that will wait for a "healthy" healthcheck (required)
# $2 Docker container name that will wait for a "healthy" healthcheck and will be used to run the execution command (required)
# $3 The actual execution command that will be ran (required). When "npm_deploy", all tokens will be included in execution of
#     "npm run jsdoc-deploy" and "npm publish"
attempt=0
health1=checking
health2=checking
while [ $attempt -le 79 ]; do
  attempt=$(( $attempt + 1 ))
  echo "Waiting for docker healthcheck on services $1 ($health1) and $2 ($health2): attempt: $attempt..."
  if [[ health1 != "healthy" ]]; then
    health1=$(docker inspect -f {{.State.Health.Status}} $1)
  fi
  if [[ $health2 != "healthy" ]]; then
    health2=$(docker inspect -f {{.State.Health.Status}} $2)
  fi
  if [[ $health1 == "healthy" && $health2 == "healthy"  ]]; then
    echo "Docker healthcheck on services $1 ($health1) and $2 ($health2) - executing: $3"
    docker exec -it $2 bash -c "$3"
    [[ $? != 0 ]] && { echo "Failed to execute \"$3\" in docker container \"$2\"" >&2; exit 1; }
    break
  fi
  sleep 2
done
if [[ $health1 != "healthy" || $health2 != "healthy"  ]]; then
  echo "Failed to wait for docker healthcheck on services $1 ($health1) and $2 ($health2) after $attempt attempts"
  docker logs --details $1
  docker logs --details $2
  exit 1
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

On Mac OS X (M1 chip) - I went with `docker version` over `docker info`, as
it turns out to be slightly faster to call the former in my case, as shown below.

```
$ time ( docker info >/dev/null 2>&1 )
( docker info > /dev/null 2>&1; )  0.11s user 0.18s system 39% cpu 0.722 total
$ time ( docker version >/dev/null 2>&1 )
( docker version > /dev/null 2>&1; )  0.05s user 0.05s system 39% cpu 0.238 total
```

So, *238ms* vs *722ms* -- it's more than twice as fast to opt with `docker version`!

In my Bash script, I added this to check if the Docker daemon is running:

```bash
# Check if docker is running
if ! docker version >/dev/null 2>&1; then
    echo "Docker does not seem to be running, run it first and retry!"
    exit 1
fi
```