# How to check if Docker is running on Windows?

Tags: windows, powershell, docker, cmd

I'd like to know how to check if Docker is running on Windows by means of the command line (cmd or powershell).

Although, I've found several posts indicating the solution to this, they are for Linux environments:

[How to check if docker is running or not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43721513/how-to-check-if-docker-is-running-or-not)

[How to check if docker daemon is running?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43978837/how-to-check-if-docker-daemon-is-running)

I couldn't get the answer for Windows systems.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Try running either of these commands on Powershell or cmd, if docker is installed, you should get a error free response:

```
docker --version
```

OR

```
docker-compose --version
```

OR

```
docker ps
```

Comment: I would recommend `docker ps` or `docker info` for cross-platform use. Unfortunately, `docker --version` completes successfully on other platforms like macOS even when Docker isn't running.

Comment: "docker ps" (checks that docker is there AND running) is better than "docker --version" (only checks that docker is installed). The "docker ps" check works on Mac, Windows, and Ubuntu (probably works all Linux flavors but I use Ubuntu so that's what I'll report on)

Comment: Use docker --help command

Answer (score 19):

Afford two methods:

1. `docker version`

   This method works both for `cmd` & `powershell`, but if for `cmd`, you need to use `echo %errorlevel%` to check the result.

   If `docker daemon` is running, it will be like next:

   ```
   PS C:\> docker version
   Client: Docker Engine - Community
   Version:           18.09.2
   API version:       1.39
   Go version:        go1.10.8
   Git commit:        6247962
   Built:             Sun Feb 10 04:12:31 2019
   OS/Arch:           windows/amd64
   Experimental:      false

   Server: Docker Engine - Community
    Engine:
     Version:          18.09.2
     API version:      1.39 (minimum version 1.12)
     Go version:       go1.10.6
     Git commit:       6247962
     Built:            Sun Feb 10 04:13:06 2019
     OS/Arch:          linux/amd64
     Experimental:     false
   PS C:\> echo $?
   True
   ```

   If `docker daemon` not running, it will be next:

   ```
   PS C:\> docker version
   Client: Docker Engine - Community
   Version:           18.09.2
   API version:       1.39
   Go version:        go1.10.8
   Git commit:        6247962
   Built:             Sun Feb 10 04:12:31 2019
   OS/Arch:           windows/amd64
   Experimental:      false
   Error response from daemon: An invalid argument was supplied.
   PS C:\> echo $?
   False
   ```
2. `Get-Process`:

   This method just works for `powershell`.

   If `docker daemon` is running, it will be next:

   ```
   PS C:\> Get-Process 'com.docker.proxy'
   Handles  NPM(K)    PM(K)      WS(K)     CPU(s)     Id  SI ProcessName
   -------  ------    -----      -----     ------     --  -- -----------
       205      10    11416      18860       0.13  12620   2 com.docker.proxy
   PS C:\> echo $?
   True
   ```

   If `docker daemon` is not running, it will be next:

   ```
   PS C:\> Get-Process 'com.docker.proxy'
   Get-Process : Cannot find a process with the name "com.docker.proxy". Verify the process name and call the cmdlet
   again.
   At line:1 char:1
   + Get-Process 'com.docker.proxy'
   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
       + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (com.docker.proxy:String) [Get-Process], ProcessCommandException
       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NoProcessFoundForGivenName,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetProcessCommand

   PS C:\> echo $?
   False
   ```

Comment: A Hint: `docker --version` will show show just the version. But `docker version` (without dashes) will show much more details.

Answer (score 5):

## docker info

- The operating-system independent way to check whether Docker is running is to ask Docker, using the docker info command. This option will work for both Windows and Linux distributions.
- If Docker is running when you will get result as shown below, otherwise you will get an error message:

> ```
> C:\Users\himanshu.agrawal>docker info
> Client:
>  Debug Mode: false
>  Plugins:
>   scan: Docker Scan (Docker Inc., v0.3.4)
>
> Server:
>  Containers: 1
>   Running: 0
>   Paused: 0
>   Stopped: 1
>  Images: 2
>  Server Version: 19.03.13
>  Storage Driver: overlay2
>   Backing Filesystem: extfs
>   Supports d_type: true
>   Native Overlay Diff: true
>  Logging Driver: json-file
>  Cgroup Driver: cgroupfs
>  Plugins:
>   Volume: local
>   Network: bridge host ipvlan macvlan null overlay
>   Log: awslogs fluentd gcplogs gelf journald json-file local logentries splunk syslog
>  Swarm: inactive
>  Runtimes: runc
>  Default Runtime: runc
>  Init Binary: docker-init
>  containerd version: 8fba4e9a7d01810a393d5d25a3621dc101981175
>  runc version: dc9208a3303feef5b3839f4323d9beb36df0a9dd
>  init version: fec3683
>  Security Options:
>   seccomp
>    Profile: default
>  Kernel Version: 5.4.39-linuxkit
>  Operating System: Docker Desktop
>  OSType: linux
>  Architecture: x86_64
>  CPUs: 2
>  Total Memory: 1.915GiB
>  Name: docker-desktop
>  ID: HHIB:HQRB:7VBA:LBUY:HKVJ:LFZ3:FSWZ:4ARP:74ZB:TIWO:WTMG:LHZH
>  Docker Root Dir: /var/lib/docker
>  Debug Mode: false
>  Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
>  Labels:
>  Experimental: false
>  Insecure Registries:
>   127.0.0.0/8
>  Live Restore Enabled: false
>  Product License: Community Engine
> ```

## Get-Process 'com.docker.proxy'

- This option can only be used with Windows Power Shell (just Power Shell, not even with CMD). If Docker is running you will get output as below, otherwise you will get an error message:

> ```
> PS C:\Users\himanshu.agrawal> Get-Process 'com.docker.proxy'
>
> Handles  NPM(K)    PM(K)      WS(K)     CPU(s)     Id  SI ProcessName
> -------  ------    -----      -----     ------     --  -- -----------
>     178      15    22984      25172       0.77  14224   1 com.docker.proxy
> ```

## Other options - Linux specific

- You can also use operating system utilities, such as `sudo systemctl is-active docker` or `sudo status docker` or `sudo service docker status`, or checking the service status using Windows utilities.
- Finally, you can check in the process list for the "dockerd" process,
  using commands like `ps` or `top`.

---

[Source 1](https://docs.docker.com/config/daemon/#:%7E:text=The%20operating%2Dsystem%20independent%20way,service%20status%20using%20Windows%20utilities.)

Comment: Get-Process will still work after it has been started but before it's ready. If you want to know when Docker is ready, not just started, docker info will only return a valid response when docker is started and also up and ready.

Answer (score 2):

If using wsl2 on Windows, you can use:

```
wsl -l -v
```

Output will be something like the below:

```
  NAME                   STATE           VERSION
* Ubuntu                 Stopped         1
  docker-desktop         Running         2
  docker-desktop-data    Running         2
```

Answer (score 2):

If you need a exact string only, you can use the go-lang formatting.
Example: using `docker info`

```
 C:> docker info -f "{{.OSType}}"
 windows

 C:> docker info -f "{{.Architecture}}"
 x86_64
```

Example: using `docker version`

```
 C:> docker version -f "{{.Server.Os}}"
 windows

 C:> docker version -f "{{.Client.Os}}"
 windows

 C:> docker version -f "{{.Server.Arch}}"
 amd64

 C:> docker version -f "{{.Client.Arch}}"
 amd64
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue while writing some scripts to work with Docker containers on Windows.

The answers given were not applicable for me because they just took too much time. I assumed that *"is Docker running on Windows"* also meant that the `default` VM was running. So instead the other answers I checked for the Docker `default` machine IP `192.168.99.100` which should normally be running when Docker is on. I then just pinged it:

```sh
ping -n <numberOfPings> -w <waitingTimeInMilliSeconds> 192.168.99.100

#Example:
ping -n 1 -w 1000 192.168.99.100
```

I found when Docker is running I normally get a response in less than 1ms which means the check is quite fast. This also means that it should be very robust to wait for even less than 1000ms if the Docker `default` machine is not running.

Comment: Interesting approach!

Answer (score 0):

Running `docker ps` when docker is not running will print to the error stream.  You might want to capture both the error and input stream, and then test for an error.

The following will return `true/false` without writing anything to the console:

```
$dockerIsRunning = (docker ps 2>&1 | Out-String) -match "^(?!error)"
```

#### Further Reading

- [How can I tell if Docker Desktop is running in a Powershell script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72465513/1366033)
- [How to check if the docker engine and a docker container are running?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43721513/1366033)

Answer (score -1):

In a **Windows batch script** (`.cmd` or `.bat` file extension), you can check this way if docker is running or not (for **Linux** or **Powershell**, check out [KyleMit's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75405162/1016343)):

```
docker ps 2>&1 | find /I /C "error" > NUL
if %errorlevel% EQU 0 (
    ECHO IMPORTANT: Run DOCKER before you start this script!
    TITLE DOCKER NOT RUNNING
    timeout 30
)
```

It redirects the error stream to normal output and then uses the pipe | to find the "error" in the message, then checking via the errorlevel if it was found or not.

If an error is found, it means docker is not running and the script then displays the message "Run DOCKER before you start this script!".

I have seen answers suggesting to use `docker --version`: this will always be successful if you have *installed* docker, but you can't check this way if it is running or not. But it might be useful to check whether you have docker on your machine or not (using a pattern like the one above).