# How can I tell if Docker Desktop is running in a Powershell script?

Tags: powershell, docker-desktop

I have a Powershell script in which I need to know if Docker Desktop is currently running.

I have read that one way to do it is to use `docker ps` and see if I get back a container list or an error message. But I'm struggling to make use of this in an actual script. I haven't worked out how to capture and act on the result correctly.

Here's what I have so far:

```powershell
function IsDockerDesktopRunning()
{
    $dockerPsResult = docker ps | Out-String

    Write-Host "Result is:"
    Write-Host $dockerPsResult

    if (($dockerPsResult).StartsWith("error"))
    {
        return $false
    }
    return $true
}

$isRunning = IsDockerDesktopRunning
Write-Host $isRunning
```

When when it's *not* running, the result looks like this:

```
error during connect: This error may indicate that the docker daemon is not running.: Get "http://%2F%2F.%2Fpipe%2Fdocker_engine/v1.24/containers/json": open //./pipe/docker_engine: The system cannot find the file specified.
Result is:

True
```

As you can see, it looks the output from the `docker ps` command gets output as it's executed and the variable isn't populated.

Is there a way to correctly capture the output?
**Or**, should I tackle the problem a different way?

Comment: Could it be a white space before the error? Try `if ($dockerPSResult.Trim().StartsWith("error") {...`. That `$true` should be in a else block as well. Otherwise, it'll keep getting written to the success stream regardless if there's an error or not.

Comment: As per Abraham's comment, redirection (for command output) must be contemplated with what you are after: Details are here: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/understanding-streams-redirection-and-write-host-in-powershell. If you are an earlier version of PS, know that Write-Host empties the buffer, thus nothing to output. Unless you are using colorized output or other special Write-Host needs, it's best not to use it. Output to the screen is the PS default, otherwise, you could use Write-Output.

Comment: @AbrahamZinala - No, it's not a leading whitespace issue. The `$dockerPSResult` variable is empty. It's not been populated with the error message.

Comment: @AbrahamZinala Also, the fact that the `if` statement has a return in it means that the final return statement wouldn't be hit.

Comment: @postanote - Sorry, but I'm not sure how that addresses the question?

Comment: @DanMcCoy, my comment is as per the answer you accepted from dougmaurer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To capture the error output as well, redirect stderr to stdout like this.

```
$docker = docker ps 2>&1
```

You can use this to determine if docker desktop is running.

```
if((docker ps 2>&1) -match '^(?!error)'){
   Write-Host "Docker is running"
}
```

Comment: Hi Doug. Thanks for your answer.
I'm not actually interested in a specific container. The question is whether **Docker Desktop** is running or not.

Comment: Thanks Doug.
The regex doesn't seem to be quite right. But the first comment on how to redirect the error output does work and is what I was looking for, so I'm marking as the correct answer (I quickly worked around the regex issue).

Answer (score -2):

Since it doesn't seem possible to capture the error message in a variable, I've decided to switch the logic around and rely on the variable being empty.

```powershell
function IsDockerDesktopRunning()
{
    $dockerPsResult = docker ps
    if ($dockerPsResult)
    {
        return $true
    }
    return $false
}

$isRunning = IsDockerDesktopRunning
Write-Host $isRunning
```

The unfortunate side effect is that the error message is still printed to the screen and makes things look a bit messy. But the logic works, so I'll live with it.

EDIT: Since adding this not so great answer, Doug has updated *his* answer, which is now correct. Thanks Doug.