# Docker-compose up : Error while fetching server API version: ('Connection aborted.', ConnectionRefusedError(61, 'Connection refused'))

Tags: php, docker, docker-compose, server

I am trying to do the `docker-compose up` command in my terminal. First I navigate to the file directory where I find a docker-compose.yaml. Then I write the command. The Server is on Port 80. I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "site-packages/docker/api/client.py", line 205, in _retrieve_server_version
      File "site-packages/docker/api/daemon.py", line 181, in version
      File "site-packages/docker/utils/decorators.py", line 46, in inner
      File "site-packages/docker/api/client.py", line 228, in _get
      File "site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 543, in get
      File "site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 530, in request
      File "site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 643, in send
      File "site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 498, in send
    requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', ConnectionRefusedError(61, 'Connection refused'))
    
    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
    
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "docker-compose", line 3, in <module>
      File "compose/cli/main.py", line 67, in main
      File "compose/cli/main.py", line 123, in perform_command
      File "compose/cli/command.py", line 69, in project_from_options
      File "compose/cli/command.py", line 132, in get_project
      File "compose/cli/docker_client.py", line 43, in get_client
      File "compose/cli/docker_client.py", line 170, in docker_client
      File "site-packages/docker/api/client.py", line 188, in __init__
      File "site-packages/docker/api/client.py", line 213, in _retrieve_server_version
    docker.errors.DockerException: Error while fetching server API version: ('Connection aborted.', ConnectionRefusedError(61, 'Connection refused'))
    [12728] Failed to execute script docker-compose
```

The first error shows up two times then the second.

Comment: Do you have the `$DOCKER_HOST` environment variable set?  Is the Docker Desktop application running?

Comment: I tried: fiona@Fionas-MacBook-Pro gruppe-13 % docker run -d -p 80:80 docker/getting-started
b35edd4bbab8ec87a0ef2beb793c4bb3382d5b878949bddca096ca1374bd84e9
docker: Error response from daemon: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint modest_agnesi (097923b153f0c23cb738591b39fff9c90479e4026add561cc847124d71b8b888): Bind for 0.0.0.0:80 failed: port is already allocated.

Do you have an idea?

Comment: No current answers here helped me to resolve.

Answer (score 234):

Add your user to docker group and try again.

```
sudo gpasswd -a $USER docker
newgrp docker
```

If you still have the problem, you may try after logging out and login back, or reboot. Or simply do:

```
sudo su $USER
```

Note: this may also happens if docker is not running on your machine. For linux with sytemd service manager, you could verify using command:

```
systemctl status docker.service
```

Comment: What worked for me: resetting the docker, navigate to my projectfolder and do docker-compose up again.

Comment: Why in this order? I would have thought you would at first need to make a new group "docker" and then add the user to that group. If you check it with the command `groups` after the `sudo gpasswd -a $USER docker`, there is still no such group as "docker", it gets made by the `newgrp docker` in the end. Still works. Seems to map the user as the member of the group at first and matches that group name afterwards with any new group.

Answer (score 70):

just open Docker Desktop on your computer

Comment: Not a solution for cloud-based systems

Comment: Does not work on ubuntu Linux

Comment: This actually worked for me on MacOS Catalina.

Comment: I don't know why but it worked for me on ubuntu 22.04

Comment: @Noob btw docker desktop does exist on ubuntu linux

Comment: This worked for me on Ubuntu 22.04 while no other option worked

Comment: well the docker desktop does exist. but don't use it if you have used something else. it does strange things to environment, creates new docker env. actually it is the cause of why I look at this question.

Answer (score 60):

```
sudo chmod 666 /var/run/docker.sock
```

This worked for me

Comment: This is **extremely** unsafe. FYI, giving a user access to docker.sock is like giving them sudo

Comment: "extremely unsafe" and whatever, but works.

Comment: Obviously this, is not meant to be in a production server or something like that, just for testing/local purposes.

Answer (score 14):

I had the same issue and error message. In my case i had to start and enable docker service.

```
systemctl start docker
systemctl enable docker
```

Comment: `systemctl is-enabled docker` should show if docker is disabled or not

Answer (score 11):

Make sure your docker is actually running on your machine. You can use this post: [How to check if the docker engine and a docker container are running?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43721513/how-to-check-if-the-docker-engine-and-a-docker-container-are-running)

Answer (score 10):

To add clarity to [Zstack's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65240108/10907864).

I encountered this issue while trying to setup **Ansible AWX** on **Ubuntu 20.04**

> fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Error connecting: Error while fetching server API version: ('Connection aborted.', PermissionError(13, 'Permission denied'))"}
> ...ignoring

**Here's how I fixed it**:

The issue was caused because I had not added my current user to the docker group.

Create the docker group if it does not already exist.

```
sudo groupadd docker
```

Add your user to the docker group.

```
sudo usermod -aG docker $USER
```

**Log out and log back** in so that your group membership is re-evaluated.

Verify that you can run docker commands without `sudo`.

```
docker ps
```

That's all.

Comment: Doesn't work for me.

Comment: I did not need the first command `sudo groupadd docker`, I guess that docker group is there by default. Then I ran  `sudo usermod -aG docker myuser` (your code with `$USER` is better) and `sg docker -c "bash" ` and it worked. I am not sure whether the latter command was needed, someone can comment if so.

Answer (score 7):

Solution:
This means you haven’t started your docker service!

First, try to start it using

１．`sudo systemctl start docker`

２．`sudo service docker start`

３．`sudo /etc/init.d/docker restart`

**For More Info** see this docs:[here](https://techoverflow.net/2021/05/07/how-to-fix-docker-errors-dockerexception-error-while-fetching-server-api-version-connection-aborted-filenotfounderror2-no-such-file-or-directory/)

Comment: `service docker start` worked in `wsl`, also can restart docker desktop / service in OS

Answer (score 3):

The error happend to me in production and linux machines, specially with amazon ec2 instances.

As a simple and safe solution:

First (of course, if using linux machines and systemd):

```
sudo systemctl enable docker.service
sudo systemctl start docker.service
sudo usermod -aG docker <here-your-user>
```

Make sure you logout and login again. Then, give executable permissions to docker compose binary:

```
sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
```

Try again!

Answer (score 2):

I had the same error after system and Docker updates on macOS Big Sur 11.1. I was also unable to run Docker Desktop, so I've checked the option `open at login` and simply restarted the system.

Comment: For those having issue on MacOS, this solution works for me - https://leighmcculloch.com/posts/docker-context-via-ssh-with-macos/

Answer (score 2):

This problem occurs due to docker user has no right access ,

After giving the right permissions and reconnecting to the server should solve the issue,

You can create the docker user if not exist

> sudo groupadd docker

Add docker user to user group

> usermod -aG docker $USER

Then reconnect to the server, it should work.

For more information this link is usefull :
https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/linux-postinstall/

Answer (score 2):

I tried almost all the solutions above but for some reason what worked for me was sourcing the `bashrc` file:

`source ~/.bashrc`.

After this the error went away.

Comment: thanks! works for me. I also tried almost solutions above.... but none of them worked.

Answer (score 1):

you can give docker socket read and write permission for other users by executing this command in your machine

```
sudo chmod o+rw /var/run/docker.sock
```

Answer (score 0):

I've just encountered this problem on my Mac after upgrading to 4.17.0. I solved the problem by downgrading again to 4.16.2 from https://docs.docker.com/desktop/release-notes/.

Answer (score 0):

For who is using WSL, make sure the WSL settings enabled, and restart Docker Desktop

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I got this error after running Docker Desktop once, and it was because it changed my context and thus the Docker endpoint being used

I fixed it by running this command

`docker context use default`

You can also list your contexts with `docker context list`

Answer (score 0):

happened to me as well when i tried

```
docker-compose up
```

without sudo. When added sudo command to start of that command things work fine in windows wsl. A file permission thing it seem.