# docker.errors.DockerException: Error while fetching server API version

Tags: python, linux, docker, docker-compose

I want to install this module but there is something wrong when I try the step `docker-compose build ...`

I tried to update the Docker version and restart Docker many times. But it didn't work.

```
git clone https://github.com/uhh-lt/158.git
cd 158
docker-compose build
```

```
File "/home/ming/.local/bin/docker-compose", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/home/ming/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/compose/cli/main.py", line 67, in main
    command()
  File "/home/ming/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/compose/cli/main.py", line 123, in perform_command
    project = project_from_options('.', options)
  File "/home/ming/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/compose/cli/command.py", line 60, in project_from_options
    return get_project(
  File "/home/ming/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/compose/cli/command.py", line 131, in get_project
    client = get_client(
  File "/home/ming/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/compose/cli/docker_client.py", line 41, in get_client
    client = docker_client(
  File "/home/ming/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/compose/cli/docker_client.py", line 170, in docker_client
    client = APIClient(**kwargs)
  File "/home/ming/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/docker/api/client.py", line 188, in __init__
    self._version = self._retrieve_server_version()
  File "/home/ming/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/docker/api/client.py", line 212, in _retrieve_server_version
    raise DockerException(
docker.errors.DockerException: Error while fetching server API version: ('Connection aborted.', FileNotFoundError(2, 'No such file or directory'))
```

##### Update 2020-11-23

Thanks for two of you helping me with the error! I tried the commend but can't connect to my Docker:

```bash
ming@KITM-7664:~$ sudo /etc/init.d/docker start
[sudo] password for ming:
 * Starting Docker: docker                                                                                       [ OK ]

ming@KITM-7664:~$ which docker
/usr/bin/docker

ming@KITM-7664:~$ docker version
Client: Docker Engine - Community
 Version:           19.03.13
 API version:       1.40
 Go version:        go1.13.15
 Git commit:        4484c46d9d
 Built:             Wed Sep 16 17:02:52 2020
 OS/Arch:           linux/amd64
 Experimental:      false
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?

ming@KITM-7664:~$ systemctl status docker
System has not been booted with systemd as init system (PID 1). Can't operate.
Failed to connect to bus: Host is down

ming@KITM-7664:~$ systemctl start docker
System has not been booted with systemd as init system (PID 1). Can't operate.
Failed to connect to bus: Host is down

ming@KITM-7664:~$ sudo /etc/init.d/docker start
 * Starting Docker: docker                                                                                       [ OK ]

ming@KITM-7664:~$ docker version
Client: Docker Engine - Community
 Version:           19.03.13
 API version:       1.40
 Go version:        go1.13.15
 Git commit:        4484c46d9d
 Built:             Wed Sep 16 17:02:52 2020
 OS/Arch:           linux/amd64
 Experimental:      false
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?
```

Comment: make sure that docker desktop is up running. In my case I got docker.errors.DockerException: Error while fetching server API version: (2, 'CreateFile', 'The system cannot find the file specified.') because I manually stopped docker desktop. Once I restarted it, everthing worked as expected.

Comment: In addition to What @YJDev said, I installed docker-desktop, which I guess takes over starting the docker service. So once I started up docker-desktop, docker-compose ran like a charm!

Answer (score 369):

Are you sure docker is running on your system? You can get that error when compose is not able to connect to docker via docker socket (if any other way for connection is not defined).

If you are running on linux, usually you can run `systemctl status docker` to check if docker daemon is running and `systemctl start docker` to start it.

It would help to tell what OS and `docker version` are you using.

Comment: Thank you for the help!! I'm using ubuntu and the docker version is 19.03.13. I tried to use 'systemctl start docker' to start but there is something wrong so I tried 'sudo /etc/init.d/docker start'. Didn't work either...

Comment: I understand. It sounds a bit like WSL... please try "sudo service docker start" and see if it's working. This is in case it's WSL, have you tried to start it as administrator (by right clicking from start menu)?

Comment: "sudo service docker start" didn't work so I opened the windows powershell(administrator), run "docker-compose build " and the other error happened'/usr/bin/env: ‘python3\r’: No such file or directory
ERROR: Service 'frontend' failed to build : The command '/bin/sh -c ./frontend_assets.py' returned a non-zero code: 127'

Comment: It seems like I have to install dos2unix in ubuntu...so I backed to ubuntu, tried to install powershell into ubuntu...after installed powershell and dos2unix, run 'docker version' still cannot connect..error:'Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?'

Comment: Yes, until docker daemon does not start (the "sudo service docker start" supposed to do that), the socket file doesn't exists and docker and compose cannot connect to the daemon. First thing you should do is find out why docker daemon doesn't start. Please try and follow the informations here (including trying to run dockerd manually and also see the troubleshooting guide on the same page): https://docs.docker.com/config/daemon/

Comment: Wonder why isn't this upvoted more? Should be a common error and this was the spot-on answer.

Comment: Saw this error. Panicked. Saw this response. Calm.

Comment: My issue was that the docker wasn't  initiated. Then, I restarted the computer, relaunched docker and everything worked fine.

Comment: Thank you for the solution. I was trying docker commands without starting docker.

Comment: I know this is an old thread but, in the new Docker update (Windows), Docker won't work in the first run without WSL 2, so just be patient and follow Docker's provided instructions...

Answer (score 126):

set the permission like this,

```sh
sudo chmod 666 /var/run/docker.sock
```

Comment: worked for me! I originally checked "systemctl status docker" to see if docker was running—it was. I move onto this answer and it worked great. thanks!

Comment: Be careful!  Anyone who can access the Docker socket can pretty trivially root the host.  This setting can make sense on a developer system where you give yourself unrestricted `sudo` access anyways, but it may not be good security practice in other contexts.

Comment: Could you explain why this works?

Comment: Bad suggestion, downvoted. The socket file will have a group – usually `docker`. You should add yourself to that group (add your username to the group in `/etc/group`, log out, log in again) if you want to have access to the socket. Opening it up to *all* users of the machine like this is bad practice, for reasons that @DavidMaze already pointed out.

Comment: @DanielWalker it works because it gives all users access to the "socket" file – the three digits in the `chmod` command stand for user permissions, group permissions, world permissions and all three are set to 6 which means "read and write". The socket file is a channel for communicating with the Docker process, similar to a network port. Without access to this socket, you can't communicate with the Docker process (daemon). However, giving access to a particular user (you) by giving access to everyone is like removing a door entirely instead of giving someone a key to unlock the door.

Comment: This is a safer first try https://stackoverflow.com/a/68968809/363217

Comment: downgraded : it's a security hole
add your user to group docker as already said

Answer (score 41):

When you are using [WSL (Windows Subsystem for Linux)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/), you need to enable 'WSL Integration' for the required distro in [Windows Docker Desktop](https://hub.docker.com/editions/community/docker-ce-desktop-windows) (*Settings -> Resources-> WSL Integration -> Enable integration with required distros*).

[image: WSL Integration]

Comment: Actually I already this option set, but I turned it off, reload docker, then turn it on and reload the docker and it did the trick for me.

Comment: Make sure it starts with administrator

Answer (score 35):

By default, the docker command can only be run the root user or by a user in the docker group, which is automatically created during Docker’s installation process. If you want to avoid typing sudo whenever you run the docker command, add your username to the docker group:

```
sudo usermod -aG docker ${USER}
```

To apply the new group membership, log out of the server and back in, or type the following:

```
su - ${USER}
```

You will be prompted to enter your user’s password to continue.

Comment: This solution actually helped me and seems to be more safe that setting 666 permisions on docker.sock

Comment: Didn't work for me, but this worked: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64662372/docker-compose-up-error-while-fetching-server-api-version-connection-aborte

Comment: how do i create the group?

Comment: The group is created during Docker’s installation process.

Answer (score 19):

I had this issue while starting `docker-compose`. The problem was caused by `urllib3'. The fix is simple:

```
pip install 'urllib3<2'
```

Source: https://github.com/docker/docker-py/issues/3113#issuecomment-1579172104

Comment: This worked for me on Ubuntu

Comment: They've fixed this now so you should be able to upgrade the docker package instead https://github.com/docker/docker-py/issues/3113
`pip install --upgrade docker`

Answer (score 18):

`sudo service docker start`
or
`sudo service docker restart`

Comment: This is what worked for me, I am running ubuntu on WSL2.

Comment: This works for me, I am running ubuntu on Centos

Comment: Great, it works for me, I am using Ubuntu 20.04.

Answer (score 9):

Just had the same issue after updating Windows Docker desktop to it's latest version (`20.10.2, build 2291f61`). It happened that this update disabled the WSL2 integration with my virtual Ubuntu 18.04, which I use to run most projects.

I solved it this way:

1. Open Docker Desktop
2. Go to Settings > Resources > WSL Integration
3. Make sure that your distribution is enabled
4. Restart Docker
5. Without the need of restarting WSL2, docker should work again

[image: Docker Desktop distro integration]

Answer (score 7):

You don't have permission to use the docker socket, by default only the `docker` group can access it. You can verify this with `ls -l /var/run/docker.sock`, which will print something like:

```
srw-rw----. 1 root docker 0 Oct  4 18:04 /var/run/docker.sock
```

To be able to access the socket and use Docker, add yourself to the Docker group with the following command:

`sudo usermod -a -G docker $(whoami)`

Then logout and back in. Docker will now work.

Comment: this fixed it for me in ubuntu

Answer (score 6):

I had a similar issue and it turned out to be due to Docker server not running. I started the app and then ran `docker-compose up` and it started working fine. Hope it helps anyone who's caught in a similar situation. :-)

Comment: how do you start docker server? Ubuntu server

Answer (score 6):

In macOS with Docker Desktop 4.18, check `Enable default docker socket` in `Settings -> Advanced` section.

Comment: this worked on MacOS

Comment: Confirming that this enabled the Docker SDK for Python on my M1 Mac Ventura 13.3.1 to work. I tested 
client = docker.from_env() and 
client = docker.DockerClient(base_url='unix://var/run/docker.sock') 
and I arrived at a DockerException with Connection Aborted error but now it does  execute properly on my system. Docker Desktop Version 4.22.1

Answer (score 5):

Make sure you check the box for 'use Docker Compose V2'. It solved for me.
[docker desktop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KtIo1.png)

Comment: This can be found in Settings -> General -> User Docker Compose V2 -> Apply and Restart

Answer (score 3):

If you're using `docker-compose` inside `podman` try the below command to resolve this issue `"docker.errors.DockerException: Error while fetching server API version: ('Connection aborted.', FileNotFoundError(2, 'No such file or directory'))"`

```
systemctl start podman.socket
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm also get this error when i try to run the `docker-compose` and docker desktop is turn off, i think that is bug in docker-compose that not notify the user it that the problem is becuse the docker service is down, same as the docker cli that throw correct error:

```
C:\Users\x\IdeaProjects\mongo-exmple>docker pull node
Using default tag: latest
error during connect: This error may indicate that the docker daemon is not running.: Post "http://%2F%2F.%2Fpipe%2Fdocker_engine/v1.24/images/create?fromImage=node&tag=latest": open //./pipe/docker_engine: The system cannot find 
the file specified.
```

Answer (score 2):

At Linux (at least Ubuntu 18.04.x), you sometimes need to log out and re-login your X user session. Logging out of bash or out of the terminal window and re-logging in is not enough, see for example https://askubuntu.com/questions/1161020/groups-and-groups-user-show-different-groups-dialout-is-missing

Answer (score 2):

In Mac OS and Windows sometimes that's enough to start up docker application and this error is because of loss of docker daemon in system.

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem while using ubuntu 22.04 wsl on windows and then I solve it like this

```
sudo update-alternatives --config iptables
```

it will show something like this

```
 Selection    Path                       Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
  0            /usr/sbin/iptables-nft      20        auto mode
* 1            /usr/sbin/iptables-legacy   10        manual mode
  2            /usr/sbin/iptables-nft      20        manual mode
```

then press 1

```
Press <enter> to keep the current choice[*], or type selection number: 1
```

Start docker using services

```
sudo service docker start
```

Answer (score 2):

My issue was I was not signed into docker desktop.

Answer (score 2):

I had this error running docker compose in Linux Subsystem on Win10, the problem was that I have forgotten to start Docker Desktop application

Answer (score 2):

On MacOS I installed XCode after Docker (Docker Desktop). Afterwards my Python App (testcontainers) was unable to communicate to Docker (stopped working). Running `/Applications/Docker.app/Contents/MacOS/uninstall` and open Docker again fixed it for me on M1 MacBook. (Removes config, images, ...)

Comment: Thank you, this solved the issue for me (M1 MacBook)

Answer (score 1):

I had this happen on a Mac after doing an OS update.

I was able to run `docker` on the command line but Docker Desktop wasn't running - starting Docker Desktop up fixed the issue.

Answer (score 1):

On macOS, deleting Docker's data has worked for me:

```
rm -rf ~/Library/Containers/com.docker.*
```

It's a crude solution, and I wouldn't recommend if you have any precious data in your local docker install.

Answer (score 0):

In Windows exiting from Docker and running it again sometimes helps. Apparently not always docker starts up properly.

Comment: For me it was related to enabled corporate VPN. I disabled it and then docker started up successfully....

Answer (score 0):

try to run your command with `sudo`.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea the cause of error but reinstalling `requests` and `urllib3` worked for me.

```
pip install --force-reinstall 'requests<2.29.0' 'urllib3<2.0'
```