# Using moto to communiate with server

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, testing, integration-testing, moto

I'm trying to use `moto` to implement integration testing and trying to test some custom resources to be implemented with cloudformation. I'm using the example provided in the github [page](https://github.com/spulec/moto/blob/master/tests/test_cloudformation/test_cloudformation_custom_resources.py). I've slightly altered the example to fit my development environment and to accept `yaml` files instead of `json`s which also fits my deployment strategy. I've gone over the documentation and the code in the example and have launched a server which is whats needed by the `cf.create_stack` command. The example calls a method

```
def wait_for_log_msg(expected_msg, log_group): 
    ...
```

The method returns `True` and a `set` if the `expected_msg` is in the received messages, else it returns `False` and a `set` (The code is found below).

**PROBLEM:**

As per the example the message sent is `Status code: 200`, That message is not received and when I print through the messages I get `failed executing http.request`. I'm under the assumption that this is due to some faulty approach I have with `motoserver`.

**QUESTION:**

How can I get `motoserver` and specifically the `logstream` to output the desired `Status code: 200` message?

**ATTEMPTS:**

I tried starting `motoserver` using `docker` but I got the following error:

```
{"error running docker: Error while fetching server API version: ('Connection aborted.', FileNotFoundError(2, 'No such file or directory'))"}
```

I then switched to running `motoserver` directly by calling it in the terminal using

```
moto_server -p5000
```

which yields a failure and when I print the log message I get (after formatting to make it easier to read):

```
{
    '\x1b[32mEND RequestId: 50fe51a1-46e2-16d2-c274-8a50604d2be9\x1b[0m', 
    "send(..) failed executing http.request(..): HTTPConnectionPool(host='host.docker.internal', port=5000): Max retries exceeded with url: /cloudformation_us-east-1/cfnresponse?stack=arn:aws:cloudformation:us-east-1:123456789012:stack/stack10d4d2/ce9420fc-d0e5-4e71-949b-893537701776 (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f58b9eabf40>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused'))", 
    '\x1b[32mSTART RequestId: 50fe51a1-46e2-16d2-c274-8a50604d2be9 Version: $LATEST\x1b[0m', 
    '', 
    "[WARNING]\t2022-05-01T05:07:18.969Z\t50fe51a1-46e2-16d2-c274-8a50604d2be9\tRetrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f58b9eab520>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused')': /cloudformation_us-east-1/cfnresponse?stack=arn:aws:cloudformation:us-east-1:123456789012:stack/stack10d4d2/ce9420fc-d0e5-4e71-949b-893537701776", 
    "[WARNING]\t2022-05-01T05:07:18.968Z\t50fe51a1-46e2-16d2-c274-8a50604d2be9\tRetrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f58b9eab1f0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused')': /cloudformation_us-east-1/cfnresponse?stack=arn:aws:cloudformation:us-east-1:123456789012:stack/stack10d4d2/ce9420fc-d0e5-4e71-949b-893537701776", 
    '\x1b[32mREPORT RequestId: 50fe51a1-46e2-16d2-c274-8a50604d2be9\tInit Duration: 183.50 ms\tDuration: 8.25 ms\tBilled Duration: 9 ms\tMemory Size: 128 MB\tMax Memory Used: 27 MB\t\x1b[0m', 
    "{
        'RequestType': 'Create', 
        'ServiceToken': 'arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:123456789012:function:stack10d4d2-InfoFunction-M4ZP2MX8XYLL', 
        'ResponseURL': 'http://host.docker.internal:5000/cloudformation_us-east-1/cfnresponse?stack=arn:aws:cloudformation:us-east-1:123456789012:stack/stack10d4d2/ce9420fc-d0e5-4e71-949b-893537701776', 
        'StackId': 'arn:aws:cloudformation:us-east-1:123456789012:stack/stack10d4d2/ce9420fc-d0e5-4e71-949b-893537701776', 
        'RequestId': '046dc61f-d786-4672-b1a9-48eb286593e2', 
        'LogicalResourceId': 'CustomInfo', 
        'ResourceType': 'Custom::Info', 
        'ResourceProperties': {
            'ServiceToken': 'arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:123456789012:function:stack10d4d2-InfoFunction-M4ZP2MX8XYLL', 
            'Region': 'us-east-1', 
            'MyProperty': 'stuff'
        }
    }", 
    'http://host.docker.internal:5000/cloudformation_us-east-1/cfnresponse?stack=arn:aws:cloudformation:us-east-1:123456789012:stack/stack10d4d2/ce9420fc-d0e5-4e71-949b-893537701776', 
    '{
        "Status": "SUCCESS", 
        "Reason": "See the details in CloudWatch Log Stream: 2022/05/01/[$LATEST]b39c266d1989dc1bc8ec6dfecf2154d7", 
        "PhysicalResourceId": "2022/05/01/[$LATEST]b39c266d1989dc1bc8ec6dfecf2154d7", 
        "StackId": "arn:aws:cloudformation:us-east-1:123456789012:stack/stack10d4d2/ce9420fc-d0e5-4e71-949b-893537701776", 
        "RequestId": "046dc61f-d786-4672-b1a9-48eb286593e2", 
        "LogicalResourceId": "CustomInfo", 
        "NoEcho": false, 
        "Data": {
            "info_value": "special value"
        }
    }', 
    'Response body:', 
    'null', 
    "[WARNING]\t2022-05-01T05:07:18.970Z\t50fe51a1-46e2-16d2-c274-8a50604d2be9\tRetrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f58b9eab730>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused')': /cloudformation_us-east-1/cfnresponse?stack=arn:aws:cloudformation:us-east-1:123456789012:stack/stack10d4d2/ce9420fc-d0e5-4e71-949b-893537701776"
}
```

Of which I think the most interesting part is:

```
"send(..) failed executing http.request(..): HTTPConnectionPool(host='host.docker.internal', port=5000): Max retries exceeded with url: /cloudformation_us-east-1/cfnresponse?stack=arn:aws:cloudformation:us-east-1:123456789012:stack/stack10d4d2/ce9420fc-d0e5-4e71-949b-893537701776 (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f58b9eabf40>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused'))",
```

**CODE:**

The code for the tests

```
# Libraries
# Standard Libraries
import inspect
import json
import os
import sys
import time
from uuid import uuid4
import yaml

# Paths
PACKAGE_PARENT = ".."
SCRIPT_DIR = os.path.dirname(
    os.path.realpath(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), os.path.expanduser(__file__)))
)
sys.path.append(os.path.normpath(os.path.join(SCRIPT_DIR, PACKAGE_PARENT)))

# Third Party Librairies
import boto3
from moto import mock_cloudformation, mock_lambda, mock_logs, mock_s3, settings
import pytest
from pytest import assume

# User Defined Libraries
from .fixtures.custom_lambda import get_template
import src.app.App as lambda_function
from .test_awslambda.utilities import wait_for_log_msg


def get_log_group_name(cf, stack_name):
    ...


def get_outputs(cf, stack_name):
    ...


@pytest.fixture(scope="function")
def aws_credentials():
    """
    Mocked AWS Credentials for moto.
    """
    os.environ["AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID"] = "testing"
    os.environ["AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY"] = "testing"
    os.environ["AWS_SECURITY_TOKEN"] = "testing"
    os.environ["AWS_SESSION_TOKEN"] = "testing"
    os.environ["AWS_DEFAULT_REGION"] = "us-east-1"


@mock_cloudformation
@mock_lambda
@mock_logs
@mock_s3
def test_create_custom_lambda_resource():
    #########
    # Integration test using a Custom Resource
    # Create a Lambda
    # CF will call the Lambda
    # The Lambda should call CF, to indicate success (using the cfnresponse-module)
    # This HTTP request will include any outputs that are now stored against the stack
    # TEST: verify that this output is persisted
    ##########

    if not settings.TEST_SERVER_MODE:
        raise pytest.skip(
            "Needs a standalone MotoServer, as cfnresponse needs to connect to something"
        )

    # Create cloudformation stack
    stack_name = f"stack{str(uuid4())[0:6]}"

    code = inspect.getsource(lambda_function)
    template_body = get_template(code)
    cf = boto3.client(
        "cloudformation",
        region_name="us-east-1",
        endpoint_url="http://localhost:5000",
    )
    cf.create_stack(
        StackName=stack_name,
        TemplateBody=template_body,
        # TemplateBody=json.dumps(template_body),
        Capabilities=["CAPABILITY_IAM"],
    )

    # Verify CloudWatch contains the correct logs
    log_group_name = get_log_group_name(cf, stack_name)
    success, logs = wait_for_log_msg(
        expected_msg="Status code: 200", log_group=log_group_name
    )

    print(f"Logs should indicate success: \n{logs}")

    # Verify the correct Output was returned
    outputs = get_outputs(cf, stack_name)

    with assume:
        assert success is True
    with assume:
        assert len(outputs) == 1
```

all of which is nearly a copy paste of what is available on the github page where I change the code to import the function from another file using `inspect` feed it to a `yaml` version of a `cf` template and pass it attempt to mock the creation of a custom resource

For completeness `wait_for_log_msg`:

```
def wait_for_log_msg(expected_msg, log_group):
    logs_conn = boto3.client("logs", region_name="us-east-1")
    received_messages = []
    start = time.time()
    while (time.time() - start) < 30:
        try:
            result = logs_conn.describe_log_streams(logGroupName=log_group)
            log_streams = result.get("logStreams")
        except ClientError:
            log_streams = None  # LogGroupName does not yet exist
        if not log_streams:
            time.sleep(1)
            continue

        for log_stream in log_streams:
            result = logs_conn.get_log_events(
                logGroupName=log_group,
                logStreamName=log_stream["logStreamName"],
            )
            received_messages.extend(
                [event["message"] for event in result.get("events")]
            )
        for line in received_messages:
            if expected_msg in line:
                return True, set(received_messages)
        time.sleep(1)

    return False, set(received_messages)
```

which is a copy paste of what is on the github page.

Comment: Tooooooo much code - please refine the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, MotoServer is not reachable to outside connections.
The LambdaFunction used to create the CustomResource is executed inside a Docker-container, which counts as an 'outside' connection - that's why you're seeing the `NewConnectionError`.

Try starting the MotoServer like this, which opens the server up to outside connections:

```
moto_server -h 0.0.0.0
```

(Note that I'm not specifying the port, as `5000` is the default - adjust as necessary.)

---

The Docker-exception is not related to Moto, as far as I can tell - see this SO question for possible solutions:
[docker.errors.DockerException: Error while fetching server API version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64952238/docker-errors-dockerexception-error-while-fetching-server-api-version)