# Python Docker SDK "Error while fetching server API version"

Tags: python, docker, python-poetry

In the Python Docker SDK, When I do

```
import docker

docker.from_env()
```

I see

```
docker.errors.DockerException: Error while fetching server API version: ('Connection aborted.', FileNotFoundError(2, 'No such file or directory'))
```

I have docker desktop running and this works in the terminal

```
$ docker run -it ubuntu
```

If I add a version number

```
docker.from_env(version="6.0.1")
```

it stops erroring, but it doesn't seem to matter what number I use. I also then see an error on

```
client.containers.run("ubuntu")
```

of

```
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', FileNotFoundError(2, 'No such file or directory'))
```

I'm on Ubuntu 22.04 and I'm seeing the problem with both Poetry and plain pip + venv. I've looked through the dozen or so questions about that error message and tried everything that looked relevant.

Comment: Is there more of the error than that?  Are you using Docker Desktop, or just plain Docker?  Do you have a `$DOCKER_HOST` environment variable set, or a non-default `docker context`?

Comment: @DavidMaze will get more error logs. Docker desktop. re `$DOCKER_HOST` probably not (nothing shows in a fresh terminal). Don't know what the `docker context` is so probably default

Comment: I have a docker context `desktop-linux` in addition to my `default` (if I `docker context list`). Each context has a different endpoint

Comment: This seems the same as [docker/docker-py#3059](https://github.com/docker/docker-py/issues/3059), and that issue suggests a symlink-based workaround.  It may be a problem specifically with Docker Desktop 4.13.0.  Docker Desktop isn't really necessary on native Linux, though; if you uninstall it and use a non-VM Docker daemon, do things work better?

Comment: @DavidMaze that looks likely. I may well remove docker desktop now it's got in the way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My final solution was to uninstall Docker Desktop and install Docker Engine instead. I had to manually delete some Docker config files left over after installation too.

Comment: For me reinstalling Docker Desktop was also working.

Comment: Same here on MacOS after installing xcode. See here the details to uninstall https://stackoverflow.com/a/76318769/3703307

Answer (score 0):

If you're running MacOS, uninstall Docker using: `/Applications/Docker.app/Contents/MacOS/uninstall` and then install a fresh version for Docker Desktop. Be sure to choose the appropriate chipset.