# Run container in Airflow DAG

Tags: python, docker, airflow

I am running Docker Desktop on MacOS (m1 chip). I used docker-compose to run my Airflow instance.
From now I am trying to run a container in my DAG as followed :

```py
from datetime import datetime

from airflow import DAG
from airflow.decorators import task
from airflow.operators.bash import BashOperator
from airflow.providers.docker.operators.docker import DockerOperator

with DAG(dag_id="pipeline", 
         start_date=datetime(2023, 10, 4), 
         schedule_interval="13 7 * * *") as dag:


    extract = DockerOperator(
        api_version='auto', 
        docker_url='unix://var/run/docker.sock',
        command='echo Hello World',
        image='ubuntu',
        network_mode='bridge',
        task_id='docker_op_tester'
    ) 

    extract
```

But I got the following error while my DAG is running :

```
docker.errors.DockerException: Error while fetching server API version: ('Connection aborted.', PermissionError(13, 'Permission denied'))
```

Do someone knows how I can fix this issue ?

Thank you for you help. Yohan.

PS : I added this to the volume part of my docker-compose :

```yaml
volumes:
  - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
```

Comment: Check out this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64952238/docker-errors-dockerexception-error-while-fetching-server-api-version