# As no valid configuration was found, execution cannot continue, when i run DataJpaTest

Tags: spring, junit, spring-data-jpa, testcontainers

I have application that create Course and Instructor, for this application i write some test. But they does not work correctly. Few days ago, everything work correctly, but today not!
So when i run my DataJpaTest, i have some problem

```
18:07:52.849 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper - Neither @ContextConfiguration nor @ContextHierarchy found for test class [CourseDaoTest]: using SpringBootContextLoader
18:07:52.854 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractContextLoader - Could not detect default resource locations for test class [spring.dao.CourseDaoTest]: no resource found for suffixes {-context.xml, Context.groovy}.
18:07:52.876 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper - Using ContextCustomizers for test class [CourseDaoTest]: [ExcludeFilterContextCustomizer, DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizer, MockitoContextCustomizer, TestRestTemplateContextCustomizer, DisableObservabilityContextCustomizer, PropertyMappingContextCustomizer, Customizer, DynamicPropertiesContextCustomizer]
18:07:53.003 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper - Using TestExecutionListeners for test class [CourseDaoTest]: [ServletTestExecutionListener, DirtiesContextBeforeModesTestExecutionListener, ApplicationEventsTestExecutionListener, MockitoTestExecutionListener, DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener, DirtiesContextTestExecutionListener, TransactionalTestExecutionListener, SqlScriptsTestExecutionListener, EventPublishingTestExecutionListener, ResetMocksTestExecutionListener, RestDocsTestExecutionListener, MockRestServiceServerResetTestExecutionListener, MockMvcPrintOnlyOnFailureTestExecutionListener, WebDriverTestExecutionListener, MockWebServiceServerTestExecutionListener]
18:07:53.004 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDirtiesContextTestExecutionListener - Before test class: class [CourseDaoTest], class annotated with @DirtiesContext [false] with mode [null]
18:07:53.067 [main] DEBUG org.testcontainers.utility.TestcontainersConfiguration - Testcontainers configuration overrides will be loaded from file:/C:/Users/Java/.testcontainers.properties
18:07:53.073 [main] WARN org.testcontainers.utility.TestcontainersConfiguration - Attempted to read Testcontainers configuration file at file:/C:/Users/Java/.testcontainers.properties but the file was not found. Exception message: FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\Java\.testcontainers.properties (The system cannot find the file specified)
18:07:53.075 [main] DEBUG org.testcontainers.utility.TestcontainersConfiguration - Testcontainers configuration overrides will be loaded from file:/C:/Users/Java/git/CourseSystem/CourseSystem/target/test-classes/testcontainers.properties
18:07:53.077 [main] INFO org.testcontainers.utility.ImageNameSubstitutor - Image name substitution will be performed by: DefaultImageNameSubstitutor (composite of 'ConfigurationFileImageNameSubstitutor' and 'PrefixingImageNameSubstitutor')
18:07:53.094 [main] DEBUG org.testcontainers.dockerclient.DockerClientProviderStrategy - Trying out strategy: NpipeSocketClientProviderStrategy
18:07:53.094 [main] DEBUG org.testcontainers.dockerclient.DockerClientProviderStrategy - DOCKER_HOST socket file '//./pipe/docker_engine' does not exist
18:07:53.094 [main] DEBUG org.testcontainers.dockerclient.DockerClientProviderStrategy - strategy NpipeSocketClientProviderStrategy did not pass the test
18:07:53.097 [main] INFO org.testcontainers.dockerclient.DockerMachineClientProviderStrategy - docker-machine executable was not found on PATH ([C:/Users/Java/eclipseEE/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.justj.openjdk.hotspot.jre.full.win32.x86_64_19.0.1.v20221102-1007/jre/bin/server, C:/Users/Java/eclipseEE/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.justj.openjdk.hotspot.jre.full.win32.x86_64_19.0.1.v20221102-1007/jre/bin, C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath, C:\Windows\System32, C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Shell 8.0\bin\, C:\Users\Java\AppData\Local\GitHubDesktop\bin, C:\maven\tools\apache-maven-3.8.5\bin, C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8\bin, C:\Program Files\Git\cmd, C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\NVIDIA NvDLISR, C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\resources\bin, C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Shell 8.0\bin\, %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps, C:\Users\Java\AppData\Local\GitHubDesktop\bin, %M2%, C:Program Files\Java\jdk1.8\bin, C:\Program Files (x86)\KeyMan, C:\Users\Java\eclipseEE\eclipse])
18:07:53.098 [main] ERROR org.testcontainers.dockerclient.DockerClientProviderStrategy - Could not find a valid Docker environment. Please check configuration. Attempted configurations were:
As no valid configuration was found, execution cannot continue.
See https://www.testcontainers.org/on_failure.html for more details.
18:07:53.100 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDirtiesContextTestExecutionListener - After test class: class [CourseDaoTest], class annotated
```

My Test

```
@DataJpaTest
@AutoConfigureTestDatabase (replace = AutoConfigureTestDatabase.Replace.NONE)
@Sql (scripts = {"C:\\Users\\Java\\eclipse-workspace\\CourseSystem\\db\\clear.sql", "C:\\Users\\Java\\eclipse-workspace\\CourseSystem\\db\\insert.sql   "})
class CourseDaoTest extends AbstractTest{
    
    @Autowired
    private CourseDao courseDao;
    
    @Test
    void findCoursesByCourseNameContains() {
        List <Course> courses = courseDao.findCourseBycourseName("Rubby");
        int expectedResult = 2;
        assertEquals(expectedResult, courses.size());
        
}
    
    @Test
    void getCoursesByStudentId () {
        List <Course> courses = courseDao.getCourseBystudentId(1L);
        int expectedResult = 1;
        assertEquals(expectedResult, courses);
        
    }
    
}
```

If somebody know where is problem, please say me , tnx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Could not find a valid Docker environment. Please check configuration.
> Attempted configurations were: As no valid configuration was found,
> execution cannot continue.

The error message already gives you some hint. Together with your description that it worked several days ago but suddenly does not work now , I believe you forget to start the docker runtime environment when you run the test.

You can use `docker info` or the ways mentioned at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43721513/how-to-check-if-the-docker-engine-and-a-docker-container-are-running) to check if docker really start. If not , start it and run the test again.