# Docker metadata from `docker inspect` - is it read only?

Tags: docker, inspect

Docker's `docker inspect` gives me some metadata about a container, like:

```
    "Mounts": [
        {
            "Type": "bind",
            "Source": "/home/ondra/work/CI-CD/volumes/jenkins_home",
            "Destination": "/var/jenkins_home",
            "Mode": "",
            "RW": true,
            "Propagation": "rprivate"
        },
```

It's quite tempting for me to manipulate these values but I haven't found a way to.

Are these metadata generated on the fly? Or is there a way (an API perhaps?) to change those?

Comment: Any update on this?

Answer (score 2):

Containers keep most of this information at json files located at:

- `/var/lib/docker/containers/2acf6...[your container id]`

I've read about people stopping the `docker daemon`, doing changes to these files and restarting the daemon (for example [here](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/8838#issuecomment-117284347) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29841146/1561148)) but I think this is hackish.

Containers are considered to be ephemeral. So, `stop` / `remove` your container and `run` a new one with the new configuration.

---

**Update:** I've just found `docker update` and `docker container update` which gives access to some configuration options. (They are not supported for Windows containers).

> ## [docker update](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/update/)
>
> Update configuration of one or more containers
>
> Usage: `docker update [OPTIONS] CONTAINER [CONTAINER...]`

Comment: Also docker-compose is quite handy to quickly remove / run containers.