# What to do if the docker container hangs and does not respond to any command other than ctrl+c?

Tags: docker, dockerfile, containers, nvidia-docker, docker-run

I have been running a nvidia docker image since 13 days and it used to restart without any problems using `docker start -i <containerid>` command. But, today while I was downloading pytorch inside the container, download got stuck at 5% and gave no response for a while.

I couldn't exit the container either by `ctrl+d or ctrl+c`. So, I exited the terminal and in new terminal I ran this `docker start -i <containerid>` again. But ever since this particular container is not responding to any command. Be it start/restart/exec/commit ...nothing! any command with this container ID or name is just non-responsive and had to exit out of it only after `ctrl+c`

I cannot restart the docker service since it will kill all running docker containers.
Cannot even stop the container using this  `docker container stop <containerid>`

Please help.

Comment: I'd typically expect `docker stop container_id` to work; if it doesn't, you may be down to more extreme measures like rebooting the host or restarting Docker Desktop.  (IME it's unusual to use `docker start` at all; once you've stopped the container, `docker rm` it and `docker run` a new one.)

Comment: I have made many installs on that image that is why cannot remove it and reinstall everything again.

Comment: I'm not clear what you mean.  Is your image's `Dockerfile` checked into source control?  You can always `docker build` it again when you need to.

Comment: I used docker for the first time and tried many things unless this container for nvidia/tensorflow1   nvcr.io/nvidia/tensorflow:22.01-tf1-py3 worked for me. I started using it from simple commands like docker pull and docker run and then to restart I used docker start. I don't have any dockerfile associated with it.

Comment: If you've `docker run` a container and are installing software in that running container, you've done the equivalent of booting a system to only a RAM disk, and anything you've done will be lost when the container exits.  You _are_ going to lose data with this setup.  I'd highly recommend building a reproducible `Dockerfile` while the memory of what you've done is still fresh in your mind.

Answer (score 1):

I had to restart docker process to revive my container. There was nothing else I could do to solve it. used `sudo service docker restart` and then revived my container using docker run. I will try to build the dockerfile out of it in order to avoid future mishaps.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of docker RestartPolicy:
`docker update --restart=always <container>`
while mindful of caveats on the docker version you running.

or explore an answer by @Yale Huang from a similar question: [How to add a restart policy to a container that was already created](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26852321/docker-add-a-restart-policy-to-a-container-that-was-already-created?rq=1)

Comment: I tried this command but not helpful. As I said, any command with this container id in it argument is gonna get stuck. Is there anyway I can kill that particular docker image but still be able to restart it again.

Comment: Like I have linked in the answer, there is an option by @Yale Huang to `docker commit` your container as a new image, stop & rm the current container, and start a new container with the image.

Comment: I tried with docker commit, still it did not help.  The command I used: docker commit <container> suvidha/test_image

Answer (score 0):

Have look at this...

- https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/13488

As mentioned in my comment:
I see significant performance differences between Hyper-V and WSL. Hyper-V seems to have much faster IO access than WSL (both WSL vers. 1 and WSL vers. 2) which speeds up builds among others.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).